# False returned for File exists(); when it does Android internal storage

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-emulator

Inside a Fragment

```
    SQLiteDatabase savedDutiesDB = null;


    public void createDatabase() {

         try{


          savedDutiesDB = getActivity().openOrCreateDatabase("savedDuties",Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);


          savedDutiesDB.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS storedDuties " +
                                "(dutyBookName VARCHAR, dayOfTheWeek Int, pageNumber Int);");


          File databaseFile = getActivity().getApplicationContext().getDatabasePath("SavedDuties.db");
          Log.d("TCB","path:" + databaseFile);



   // Check if the database exists
       if (databaseFile.exists()) {
                            Log.d("TCB","database Created");

                        } else {
                            Log.d("TCB","Missing:" + databaseFile);    
                        }

                    }

                    catch(Exception e){

                        Log.e("TCB", "Error: "+e);

                    }


                }
```

Logs out

> D/TCB: path:/data/data/com.domain.appName/databases/SavedDuties.db
>   D/TCB: Missing:/data/data/com.domain.appName/databases/SavedDuties.db

However the file does exist as I can see it in Android device monitor and I can write to it.

Why could this be returning false?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating a database named `"savedDuties"`. You are trying to access the file for a database named `"SavedDuties.db"`. Those are not the same.

Comment: Absolutely, you are creating `savedDuties` and looking for `SavedDuties.db`, both string must be identical to get result `true`.

Comment: Been staring at that for hours. Didn't even notice the lower/uppercase S. Kudos

Answer (score 0):

This might be due to Permissions.

This might also be an issue of a misconstructed file path, try using : `databaseFile.getAbsoluteFile().exists()` instead.

Comment: Are permissions needed to read/write to internal file system? I thought was only needed for external